# chrome download failed - network error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, downloading-website-files

[image: Failed - Network error]

[image: Chrome Debugger window]

Screenshot 2 is the debugger window info, and below is the code used to download the file, it was running well in visual studio Chrome Emulators, but when I deploy the code, it stopped working. the same code is used in another place and that one works fine, not sure why this one doesn't work.

```
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(decimal document_id)
    {
        var DocumentForDownload = riskProfile.GetDocumentForDownload(document_id, isfordownload: true);
        byte[] byteArray = DocumentForDownload.DOCUMENT;
        var filename = DocumentForDownload.DOCUMENT_NAME + "." + DocumentForDownload.EXTENSION;
        string mimeType = "application/" + DocumentForDownload.EXTENSION;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/" + DocumentForDownload.EXTENSION;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: i checked in visual studio chrome emulator, the header contains content-length property, but when i deploy to the server, it doesn't, don't know why. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution, the transfer encoding was `chunked`, which doesn't support content-length header, so we need to specify the transfer-encoding to `identity`.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "identity")
```